# Using Jquery to manipulate checkbox of a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

i am trying to do a form which is so strange to me.

The basic concept is I have a column of product checkboxes in my form, and if you choose that product, then you need to check the relative product checkbox.

In the form, I have another two columns are the prices and sizes of the products. i want to calculate the amount of prices and sizes depends on which products are being ticked. What i only achieve so far is get the value of the product which are being checked, but not the prices and sizes' values. Also, how to do the calculation dynamically.

Here is the html, http://jsfiddle.net/DDEzm/2/

Hope some one can help, many thanks.

Comment: how are you storing the prices and sizes? it isn't indicated in your fiddle?

Comment: I just set all the textboxes are disabled.

Comment: tb1, tb2, tb3, tb4 are the prices & size?

Comment: yes, they are. one column is prices, one column is size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, this solution is based on your markup:

```
$(function(){
    $('#cb1').live('change',function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
           var val = 0;
           val = parseInt($('#tb1').val(), 10) + parseInt($('#tb2').val(), 10)
           $('#presult').val(val)             
        } else {
           $('#presult').val('0')              
        }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DDEzm/5/)

Comment: How come you guys can use the is('checked') so smoothly...... Works really good. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to get the value is the following:

```
$(function(){
    $("[name='chkProduct']").live('change',function(){
        var totalCost = 0;
        $("[name='chkProduct']").each(function(i){
            if($(this).attr("checked")) {
                var price = $(this).parent().next().find("[name='price']").val();
                var size= $(this).parent().next().next().find("[name='size']").val();
                totalCost = totalCost + (price * size);
                $("#presult").val(totalCost);
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

But you might want to add checks to make sure that it is numbers that you are trying to add, either by limiting the input, or checking when you click the checkbox. You could use javascripts `parseInt`, for instance.

Also, you could have a name, or class to identify the checkboxes. That way you don't have to write a change function for each checkbox.

**Edit**

I modified it so that it would work with all checkboxes and caluculate the total.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and advice, I would use them at the end. However, that is not really what I want. I wish I can calculate the price amount into the "presult" textbox and same thing happens to the size as well.

Comment: To add it to the presult, just write `$("#presult").val(calculatedValue);`

Comment: I did try that as well. No matter what thanks for your reply, and your code just gave me some other idea.

Comment: I updated my answer so you can see what I mean. I also changed it so that the total cost gets updated for all rows that are checked. Hope that helps.